# Get page number of total pages while asynchronous loading several pdf files with PDF.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, asynchronous, async-await, pdf.js

i´m using pdfjs to load and merge some pdf files. I know how to show page number of a pdf document, but while merging files, i´d like to show a page number based on total pages of all pdf docs. But because it's asynchronous, just using and increment a counter variable is not working.

```
var actual_page = 1;

(async function loop() {
for (url_item of urls) {
    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url_item);
        await loadingTask.promise.then(function (pdf) {
            let i = 1;
            while (i <= pdf.numPages) {
                var pageNumber = i;
                pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
                    //render pdf and print actual_page++ 
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First page show 1, second page show 3, and 2 will appear on page 10 and so it goes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need Promise.all or some equivalent to get the pages from getPage in the correct order.  That might just make your page numbering thing work.

```
var pagePromises = [];

while (i <= pdf.numPages) {
    pagePromises.push(pdf.getPage(i));
    i++;
}

Promise.all(pagePromises).then(function (allPages) {
  allPages.forEach(page => {
    // render pdf and print actual_page++
  });
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks James, but it also gave me wrong page numbers